# No qualifying bean of type MailProcessor' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: AwsService,ChimpService

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want to implement Java code which calls implementation class/service based on key or object I send. I tried this:

```
public interface MailProcessor {

    void processCreateUserMessage(CreateUserDTO createUserDTO);
} 

public interface EmailRestService {

    void processCreateUserMessage(CreateUserDTO createUserDTO);
}

@Service
public class EmailRestServiceImpl implements EmailRestService {

    private MailProcessor defaultProcessor;
    private Map<String, MailProcessor> processors;
    private String provider = "AwsService";

    @Autowired
    public EmailRestServiceImpl(MailProcessor defaultProcessor,
                           Map<String, MailProcessor> processors) {
        this.defaultProcessor = defaultProcessor;
        this.processors = processors;
    }

    @Override
    public void processCreateUserMessage(CreateUserDTO createUserDTO)
    {
        MailProcessor messageProcessor = processors.getOrDefault(provider, defaultProcessor);
        messageProcessor.processCreateUserMessage(createUserDTO);
    }
}
```

// Implementation

```
public interface EmailRestService {

    void processCreateUserMessage(CreateUserDTO createUserDTO);
}

@Component("AwsService")
public class AwsService implements MailProcessor {

    @Autowired
    public AwsService(....) {
      ..
    }

    @Override
    public void processCreateUserMessage(CreateUserDTO createUserDTO)
    {
        .....
    }
}

@Component("ChimpService")
public class ChimpService implements MailProcessor {

    @Autowired
    public ChimpService(....) {
      ..
    }

    @Override
    public void processCreateUserMessage(CreateUserDTO createUserDTO)
    {
        .....
    }
}
```

But during startup I get this exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.engine.service.MailProcessor' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: AwsService,ChimpjetService
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveNotUnique(DependencyDescriptor.java:220)
```

Can you advise how I can implement properly this code:

Answer (score 1):

You need to mark one of them as @Primary. That will tell Spring which one to choose by default if there is a conflict between which one to choose. For example, if you had a class that needed a "MailProcessor" dependency but didn't qualify it by either naming the variable like "chimpService" or using "@Qualifier". Then it will use the one you marked is "@Primary" as the default.

Comment: Thanks. Can you share is there some better design?

Comment: Not that I am aware of off the top of my head. I would just mark whichever one might be used more as the primary one. It really shouldn't matter which one is primary though since I would suggest always Qualifying the variables to get the correct dependency injected to make it easy to see what is going where.

Comment: As a suggestion I would remove the name in the "@Component". By default if you name the variable getting inject into the same as the class type you want injected, you can just name the variable the same as the class but in field format so the first letter is lowercase and then normal CamelCase. Spring automatically will connect the right bean with the right field and remove the redundancy and the need to do "@Qualifiers" since you are qualifying it by the name of your field getting injected into.